# Write a configuration file for each run in a separate directory, then launch mpirun

Tags: bash, sed, sbatch

I need to do a set of calculations by changing one parameter for each time. A calculation directory contains a control file named 'test.ctrl', a job submission file named 'job-test' and a bunch of data files. Each calculation should be submitted with the same control file name (written inside the job-test), and the output is given in those data files without changing their names, which creates an overwriting problem. For this reason, I want to automize the job submission process with a bash script so that I don't need to submit each calculation by hand.

As an example, I have done the first calculation in directory b1-k1-a1 (I choose this format of dir names to indicate calc. parameters). This test.ctrl file has the parameters:

```
    Beta=1
    Kappa=1
    Alpha=0 1
```

and I submitted this job using 'sbatch job-test' command. For the following calculations, my code should copy this whole directory with the name bX-kY-aZ, make the changes in the control file, and finally submit the job. I naively tried this writing the whole thing in the job-test file as you can see in below MWE:

```
    #!/bin/sh
    #SBATCH -N 1
    #SBATCH -n 1
    #SBATCH --time=0:15:00  ##hh:mm:ss


    for n in $(seq 0 5)
    do
    for m in $(seq 0 5)
    do
    for v in $(seq 0 5)
    do


    mkdir b$n-k$m-a$v
    cd b$n-k$m-a$v
    cp ~/home/b01-k1-a01/* .
    sed "s/Beta=1/Beta=$n/" test.ctrl
    sed "s/Kappa=1/Kappa=$m/" test.ctrl
    sed "s/Alpha=0 1/Alpha=0 $v/" test.ctrl
    cd ..<<EOF

    EOF

    mpirun soft.x test.ctrl
    
    sleep 5
    
    done
    done
    done
```

I will appreciate if you could suggest me how to make it work this way.

Comment: Do you need to run `mpirun` in the directory that contains the test.ctrl?  BTW, if that's the entire contents, you don't need to use sed.  You can do `cat >test.ctrl <<EOF` / `Beta=$n` / `Kappa=$m` / `Alpha=0 $v` / `EOF`.

Comment: Yes, all related files of a calculation should be in the same directory.

Comment: @tripleee When I realized this task should be optimized, this is how I searched internet. If you have a title idea that fits the task better, I'll be happy to change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked after I moved `cd ..` to the very end of the loops and removed sed, as suggested in the comments. Hence this works now:

```
#!/bin/sh
#SBATCH -N 1
#SBATCH -n 1
#SBATCH --time=0:15:00  ##hh:mm:ss

for n in $(seq 0 5)
do
  for m in $(seq 0 5)
  do
    for v in $(seq 0 5)
    do
        mkdir b$n-k$m-a$v
        cd b$n-k$m-a$v
        cp ~/home/b01-k1-a01/* .
        cat >test.ctrl <<EOF
Beta=$n
Kappa=$m
Alpha=0 $v
EOF
        mpirun soft.x test.ctrl
        sleep 5
        cd ..
    done
  done
done
```

Comment: `printf` might be preferable to the here document, to my mind at least. `printf '%s\n' "F" "Beta=$n" "Kappa=$m" "Alpha=0 $v" >test.ctrl`

Answer (score 0):

The immediate problem is that `sed` without any options does not modify the file at all; it just prints the results to standard output.

It is frightfully unclear what you were hoping the here document was accomplishing. `cd` does not read its standard input, so it wasn't accomplishing anything at all, anyway.

```sh
#!/bin/sh
#SBATCH -N 1
#SBATCH -n 1
#SBATCH --time=0:15:00  ##hh:mm:ss

for n in $(seq 0 5); do
  for m in $(seq 0 5); do
    for v in $(seq 0 5); do
      mkdir "b$n-k$m-a$v"
      cd "b$n-k$m-a$v"
      cp ~/home/b01-k1-a01/* .
      sed -e "s/Beta=1/Beta=$n/" \
          -e "s/Kappa=1/Kappa=$m/" \
          -e "s/Alpha=0 1/Alpha=0 $v/" ~/home/b01-k1-a01/test.ctrl >/test.ctrl
      mpirun soft.x test.ctrl
      cd ..
      sleep 5
    done
  done
done
```

Notice also the merging of multiple `sed` commands into a single script (though as noted elsewhere, maybe `printf` would be even better if that's everything which you have in the configuration file).